# How to copy/delete a entire function including function name quickly in vim?

Tags: vim

I need to delete/copy a function as below including function declaration (function foo()) by vim. I tried a suggestion like da{ but can not delete/copy the "function foo()" part.

```
function foo() {
//can be a blank line here
    console.log("Hello"); //cursor is at here
//...some other code
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Until better solutions come up, you can get away with deleting by counting the lines that the function is taking and then by typing something like `6dd` on the function declaration, in the example above.

Comment: Does `dap` work for you? If there is a line above and below the function that will Delete Around Paragraph.

Answer (score 2):

As long as the `{` is on the same line as the `function` definition itself, you can force a linewise motion ([`:help o_V`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#o_V)): `dVa{`

By default, the `[m` motion uses `{ ... }` to search, so that also wouldn't help with a function definition on a separate line. But some filetypes overload this (or the `[[` motion, for example the Vimscript filetype for `:function` ... `:endfunction`), and then `]Md[m` would work.

Another (cop-out) answer is *visual mode*, where you can incrementally refine the selection to cover what you want (e.g. `Va{ok` to include the line above the `{`). But of course this usually involves a lot of keystrokes :-(

Plugins like my [CountJump plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3130) or the [textobj-user plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2100) let you define your own motions and text objects. So with a little bit of customization effort, you can define just what you need yourself, assign it to a few keys, and use just like the built-in ones.